# .Net Core 3.1 API - Basic Deployment To IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a .Net Core 3.1 Web API. The API included EF Core and Automapper packages. Will this/should this run when deployed to IIS or are there other things/frameworks the need to be installed on IIS?

Comment: By default [it should work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#enable-the-iisintegration-components) but it is better that you [read the documentation as there is soo much to say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Prerequisites:**

1. .NET Core SDK installed on the development machine.
2. Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle on the IIS server. The bundle installs the .NET Core Runtime, .NET Core Library, and the ASP.NET Core Module. The module allows ASP.NET Core apps to run behind IIS.

For more information about "Publish an ASP.NET Core app to IIS", you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).